# What's the default password for the root user of phpMyAdmin under AMPPS on a Mac?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ampps

I've just used `AMPPS` on a Mac to install `phpMyAdmin` but cannot find the root password.

What is it or where can it be found?

If it helps phpMyAdmin was installed to `/Applications/AMPPS/www/myadmin`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`mysql` is the default password for user `root`.

http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Category:FAQs#How_to_use_AMPPS

And phpMyAdmin is by default available at http://localhost/phpmyadmin